# innerHtml Replace insert image Javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, innerhtml

The below Js Code is working. I want to add a picture here. If the value is 0 then x.png is 180 then y png.

how can I do that. I will be glad if you help.
Thank you

```js
var Bearing = document.getElementById("rptAracDetay_Label28_0");
if (Bearing.innerHTML.replace(':&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', '') == '0') { 
    document.getElementById("rptAracDetay_Label28_0").innerHTML = ':&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;North';
}
else if (Bearing.innerHTML.replace(':&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', '') == '180') { 
    document.getElementById("rptAracDetay_Label28_0").innerHTML = ':&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;South';
}
```

Comment: There is no need in refetching the element inside the conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to add an img element image after your innerHTML text.

If that is the case,

```
var Bearing = document.getElementById("rptAracDetay_Label28_0");                    
if (Bearing.innerHTML.replace(':&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', '') == '0') { 
    Bearing.innerHTML = ':&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;North'; 
    var img = document.createElement('img'); 
    img.src = 'https://xyz/x.png'; 
    Bearing.appendChild(img); 
}
else if (Bearing.innerHTML.replace(':&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', '') == '180') {
    Bearing.innerHTML = ':&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;South'; 
    var img = document.createElement('img'); 
    img.src = 'https://xyz/y.png'; 
    Bearing.appendChild(img); 
}
```

Upvote if you find it useful.

Comment: no background picture.
I want to add an image to the end of the line immediately.

Comment: End of line means under the same element with id "rptAracDetay_Label28_0" right? and you want to add img HTML element. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @ErhanŞimşek please check the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your if/else portion is being executed before actually Bearing variable initiated. So use a if condition to check if Bearing variable is actually initiated or not like:

```
if(Bearing){
    //do your stuff;
}
```

Comment: command works no problem.
I just want it to add a picture according to the values I gave to the end of the line. no background

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but I would say

```
const Bearing = document.getElementById("rptAracDetay_Label28_0");
                    
  Bearing.innerHTML.replace(':&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', '') === '0' ?
                     Bearing.innerHTML = ':&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;North' : Bearing.innerHTML = ':&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;South';
```

Also, is `'0'` and `'180'` a string or a number? Does `Bearing` needs to be capital for some reason?

Comment: command works no problem.
I just want it to add a picture according to the values I gave to the end of the line. no background